# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_filter' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

im trying to use this code into functions.php of my wordpress theme:

```
add_filter( 'tribe_events_pre_get_posts', 'redirect_from_events' );

function redirect_from_events( $query ) {

if ( is_user_logged_in() )
return;

if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->get( 'eventDisplay' ) )
return;

// Look for a page with a slug of "logged-in-users-only".
$target_page = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'name' => 'logged-in-users-only'
) );

// Use the target page URL if found, else use the home page URL.
if ( empty( $target_page ) ) {
$url = get_home_url();
} else {
$target_page = current( $target_page );
$url = get_permalink( $target_page->ID );
}

// Redirect!
wp_safe_redirect( $url );
exit;
}
```

doesnt work i get error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_filter' (T_STRING),
>   expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

I want that event page can be read only by registered users, plugin is total event calendar.

why? thanks for any help

Comment: Unsure, often the error is before the error displayed. Sorry I don't know enough about WP to help you.

Comment: Expressions (function *calls*) cannot reside in class declaration context. -- And yes: that's the very information missing from your code excerpt / question.